# Change the fling speed for Android's Numberpicker within an Alertdialog

Tags: android, numberpicker

I am using Androids Numberpicker within an alert dialog. However, as the list of values within the numberpicker is large e.g. 0-89 degrees say, I would like the fling gesture to scroll faster through the list of values as currently it is too slow. Can anyone help?

I have found things like velocity tracker and scroll states but do not understand if they are what I need.